# Copiar valor a un input que esta dentro de un footer de un datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy usando los DataTables de jQuery y me estoy encontrando con el siguiente problema: cuando pulso en un botón necesito pasarle un valor con jQuery al input que tiene el id  "tipo_venta2" de footer del datatable, pero no me resulta, me gustaría saber cómo lo tendría que hacer. ¿Cómo sería la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Aquí muestro el ejemplo mínimo, completo y ejecutable:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var table_ = $('#table_').DataTable({
    "scrollY": "300px",
    "searching": false,
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info": false,
    "columns": [
      { "width": "5%" },
      { "width": "5%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "6%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "39%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "5%" },
      { "width": "8%" }
    ],
    fixedHeader: {
      header: true,
      footer: true
    }
  });

  $("#test").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#table_ tfoot th input[id=tipo_venta2]').val("valor a  copiar de prueba");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<input id="test"  type="submit" value="test" />

<table id="table_" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #ff6a00; color: #fff">
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;" colspan="6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control_tablegrande" id="tipo_venta2" placeholder="VENTAS">
      </th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important; text-align:right"><span style="font-weight:normal !important;vertical-align:middle">Totales Iguales</span></th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;"></th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;"> </th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Me he dado cuenta que el problema ocurre cuando defino `"scrollY": "300px"`**,  que me impide que copie datos al input del footer. Como se puede ver en el siguiente código que funciona sin problemas al comentar esa línea:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var table_ = $('#table_').DataTable({
    //"scrollY": "300px",
    "searching": false,
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info": false,
    "columns": [
      { "width": "5%" },
      { "width": "5%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "6%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "39%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "5%" },
      { "width": "8%" }
    ],
    fixedHeader: {
      header: true,
      footer: true
    }
  });

  $("#test").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#table_ tfoot th input[id=tipo_venta2]').val("valor a  copiar de prueba");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<input id="test"  type="submit" value="test" />

<table id="table_" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #ff6a00; color: #fff">
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;" colspan="6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control_tablegrande" id="tipo_venta2" placeholder="VENTAS">
      </th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important; text-align:right"><span style="font-weight:normal !important;vertical-align:middle">Totales Iguales</span></th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;"></th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;"> </th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

¿Por qué ocurre el error cuando pongo ese atributo en la configuración?¿Cómo puedo hacer que me funcione en ambos casos sin problemas?

Comment: El código que compartes funciona sin problemas (como puedes ver en este [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xd8m3usw/)). ¿Qué es `#test`?¿Cuándo se crea y dónde está situado el código que le asocia el evento click?¿Recibes algún error en la consola de JS?

Comment: es un boton que tiene el id #test que realiza tal acción

Comment: <input id="test"  type="submit" value="test" />

Comment: veo q tu ejemplo funciona, pero no se porque no

Comment: Eso no ayuda mucho. ¿Dónde está `#test` en tu código?¿Y en la pregunta?¿Dónde se asocia el controlador del evento `click`? Incluso si añado un botón como el que comentas en el [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xd8m3usw/1/), éste funciona sin errores, ¿Puedes crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) donde se vea el problema? Algo me dice que el problema está en cómo/dónde se asocia el controlador del evento `click`, pero es imposible saberlo sin más información.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Ya se cual es la causa del error, o mejor dicho del bloqueo, es cuando defino el datatable en el document ready: var table_table_ingresoComprobante= $('#table_1').DataTable({
            "scrollY": "300px",........................................................
.............................
es bien raro, porque cuando no lo defino funciona, pero en caso contrario, no se puede

Comment: Es bien raro, no se que habria que hacer en ese caso

Comment: me doy cuenta que cuando defino la propiedad "columns": [... , pasa el problema

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir un ejemplo en el que se pueda ver el error? Aunque sea con datos falsos, lo que importa es que se pueda ver qué es lo que ocurre

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro, encontre la causa del error, cuando defino "scrollY": "300px", dentro de la defincion var table_table_ingresoComprobante= $('#table_1').DataTable({ ..........
sucede el problema, pero cuando no tiene, funciona, por lo menos encontré la causa del error, pero como lo haría para que no perder el scroll, si lo hago con style, perdería la responsividad del datatable

Comment: creo que existe otra forma de acceder al footer, algo como datatable.column.footer().añgoooo, pero no se como usarlo

Comment: Te digo lo mismo que dije anteriormente: tienes que crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) donde se vea el error o va a ser muy difícil ayudarte

Comment: ok, edite la pregunta, puse todo el codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que hace `datatables` es descomponer tu tabla para asignar un modelo que separe `thead` `tbody` y `tfoot` esto por lo regular ocurre  cuando se le asigna un `scrollY` entonces no funciona porque tu `tfoot` esta fuera de la tabla.

Si revisas con el inspector de código del navegador(f12) te darás cuenta, entonces tu elemento para asignar un valor al `input` quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$("#test").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#table__wrapper input#tipo_venta2').val("valor a  copiar de prueba");
});
```

Te dejo tu código completo con la modificación

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var table_ = $('#table_').DataTable({
    "scrollY": "100px",
    "searching": false,
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info": false,
    "columns": [
      { "width": "5%" },
      { "width": "5%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "6%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "39%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "5%" },
      { "width": "8%" }
    ],
    fixedHeader: {
      header: true,
      footer: true
    }
  });

  $("#test").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#table__wrapper input#tipo_venta2').val("valor a  copiar de prueba");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<input id="test"  type="submit" value="test" />

<table id="table_" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #ff6a00; color: #fff">
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;" colspan="6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control_tablegrande" id="tipo_venta2" placeholder="VENTAS">
      </th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important; text-align:right"><span style="font-weight:normal !important;vertical-align:middle">Totales Iguales</span></th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;"></th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;"> </th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema ocurre porque cuando usas el parámetro `scrollY`, el plugin de los DataTables origina varios contenedores y tablas diferentes para crear la ilusión de espacio que se indica en `scrollY`, y copia el contenido del footer a esos nuevos contenedores, entonces tu selector en jQuery deja de funcionar correctamente.

```
$('#table_ tfoot th input[id=tipo_venta2]').val("valor a  copiar de prueba");
```

O mejor dicho, sí funciona correctamente, pero no es el elemento que esperabas que seleccionara (el que está en el nuevo footer), sino el original (que está escondido en el footer original).

Una posible solución sería usar clases, de este modo TODAS las copias del `input` se le asignará el valor indicado (en lugar de sólo a la primera que se encuentre como ocurría con el id):

```
$('.tipo_venta2').val("valor a  copiar de prueba");
```

Y ya funcionará como puedes ver en este ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var table_ = $('#table_').DataTable({
    "scrollY": "300px",
    "searching": false,
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info": false,
    "columns": [
      { "width": "5%" },
      { "width": "5%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "6%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "39%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "8%" },
      { "width": "5%" },
      { "width": "8%" }
    ],
    fixedHeader: {
      header: true,
      footer: true
    }
  });

  $("#test").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tipo_venta2').val("valor a  copiar de prueba");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<input id="test"  type="submit" value="test" />

<table id="table_" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #ff6a00; color: #fff">
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
      <th>dat</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;" colspan="6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control_tablegrande tipo_venta2" id="tipo_venta2" placeholder="VENTAS">
      </th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important; text-align:right"><span style="font-weight:normal !important;vertical-align:middle">Totales Iguales</span></th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;"></th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;"> </th>
      <th style="border:0 !important;border-collapse:separate !important;"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```